# Jenkins problems with ruby-runtime v0.12

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

After an upgrade got a red box in jenkins:

> There are dependency errors loading some plugins:

[image]

When I visit plug in page: there are no upgrades available: [image]

When I visit **Available** tab, Ruby run-time is already installed with 0.12 version and there are no updates for the Gitlab Hook Plugin

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 + with openjdk 9. I switched to oracle JDK 8, the plug-in installed properly.

Check the plug-in if it's installed. It wasn't installed with gitlab plug-in install for me.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score -1):

In case of windows  issue with Jenkins try reinstall Jenkins from "Program Files x86" to `C:\Jenkins`. 
This solved issue with GitLab Hook and Ruby-runtime plugins.